# How to change navbar background on Scrollling in bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery

I like my navbar to change background color when scrolling. am using bootstrap 5. please I need help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 100) {
     $(".navbar").css("background" , "blue");
     }else{
       $(".navbar").css("background" , "#000");     
     }
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove class **bg-dark** if you want to change background color.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 100) {
      $(".navbar").removeClass('bg-dark').css("background" , "blue");
    }else{
      $(".navbar").css("background" , "").addClass('bg-dark');    
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbar-fixed/navbar-top-fixed.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container">
  <div class="bg-light p-5 rounded">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser’s viewport.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/docs/5.0/components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```